# Logic - Simplify a propositional logic expression

Tags: propositional-calculus

any help on simplifying the following propositional expression?

¬[¬( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∧ )] ∧ ( ∨ )

I have done some progress but the exercise demands only one logical operator left at the end.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  We really appreciate it if the post shows some effort and work. And, it sounds like you did do some work. So, can you please add that to your post, no matter how wrong or incomplete that may be?  That'll help us focus our feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lnot[\lnot(p \land r) \lor (\lnot p \land q)] \land (p \lor r) &=[(p\land r) \land \lnot(\lnot p \land q)] \land (p \lor r) \\
& = [(p\land r) \land ( p \lor  \lnot q)] \land (p \lor r) \\
& = [p \land r] \land (p \lor r) \\
& = p \land r 
\end{align}$$